# Geocoding with java API

Tags: java, geocoding, nominatim

I am using Nominatim java api for nomitim to get longitude and latitude attributes for given address:https://github.com/AtlisInc/Nominatim-API. For every different input longitude and latitude outputs are being same.For latitude = 51.3258094 and for longitude = 11.3400106. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code:

```
public class Geocoding(){
private volatile NominatimAPI nominatimAPI;//Use Volatile
public NominatimAPI getNominatimAPI(){
NominatimAPI result=nominatimAPI;
if(result==null){
    synchronized (this){//Synchronize for thread safety
        result=nominatimAPI;
        if (result==null){
            result=new NominatimAPI();
            nominatimAPI=result;
        }
    }
}
return result;
}

private static void mymethod2() {
    List<String> cities = Arrays.asList("Los Angeles","Berlin");
    String endpointUrl = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/";
    MapPoint mapPoint;
    Geocoding test=new Geocoding();
    for (String city : cities) {
        NominatimAPI nominatim = test.getNominatimAPI();
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setCity(city);
        nominatim.initNominatimAPI(endpointUrl);
        mapPoint = nominatim.getMapPointFromAddress(address, 18);
       System.out.println(mapPoint.getLatitude()+","+mapPoint.getLongitude());
}
}
}
```

Comment: A precision of `18` seems to be a bit extreme - have you tried to reduce the precision? The sample you linked to uses `5`...

Comment: After glancing over the code, this shouldn't matter though - as you only specified "City", `maxPrecision` is 1 anyway, as far as I can see.

Comment: Without having actually tested anything, I would recommend to add a state to your address.

Comment: There is also an open issue that seems very similar to this question - https://github.com/AtlisInc/Nominatim-API/issues/5

Comment: Thank you for your consideration.I tried them and nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `address.setCity(city);`I used `address.setCountry(city)`.For every input which refers to address for nominatim you can use with setCountry.It returns true longitude and latitude values.I don't understand why only setCountry works but it is.